# Why is a foreignObject in a text node not visible?

Tags: d3.js, svg

I have text and a `foreignObject` in a text node. I see the text ("blabla"), but not the `foreignObject` content ("Hello").

How can I debug this?

```html
<svg>
  <text class="circle-label" style="display: inline;" transform="translate(100,20)">blabla
    <foreignObject width="200" height="100" fill="red">
      <div>Hello</div>
    </foreignObject>
  </text>
</svg>
```

Comment: Because the spec does not allow to nest a `foreignObject` inside a [`text`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) element. Only animation, descriptive or text content child elements are possible at that position.

Comment: thanks a lot. What should be the container for it ? I tried rect, but I also cannot see the foreignObject inside it. I checked out w3.org and mdn, but I does not tell me what is an appropriate container.

Comment: OK I got it working by having no wrapping element for the foreignObject, the direct parent being svg, whih contain pretty much everything. Can you @altocumulus make your answer into a oneline answer so that I can accept it ? Even if it feels very basic, this might help another newbee googling with the same words as me. PS: fantastic weather here in the alps, I see some of your eponyms rising. Time to fly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The SVG 1.1 spec allows the following element types inside a [`<text>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#TextElement) element:

> **Content model:**
>
> Any number of the following elements, in any order:
> [animation elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermAnimationElement)
> [descriptive elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermDescriptiveElement)
> [text content child elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/intro.html#TermTextContentChildElement)
> [‘a’](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html#AElement)

Since the `<foreignObject>` is uncategorized in terms of the spec, it does not belong to any of those categories, and must, therefore, not be nested inside a `<text>` element.

According to the spec only [container elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element#Container_elements) may contain a `<foreignObject>` element. This category comprises the following element types: `<a>`, `<defs>`, `<g>`, `<marker>`, `<mask>`, `<missing-glyph>`, `<pattern>`, `<svg>`, `<switch>`, and `<symbol>`.